# PDF bookmarks for references and index appear as contained in the appendix. Wrong hierarchy

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, bookmarks

I am writing my B.A.'s thesis, this is the last part of the code:

```
\part*{Apéndices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{}Apéndices}
% ------     Anexos bloque 1  ---------- %
\subfile{anexos.tex}
% ------    Espacios Polacos   ---------- %
\subfile{polish.tex}
\backmatter
% ------     Referencias  ---------- %
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
% ------     Índice  ---------- %
\phantomsection
\printindex
\end{document}
```

I like it this way because I get this effect in the Table of Contents (that is, References and Index are not numbered and doesn't seem to belong to the Appendix (Apéndices)):

[image]

However what I find really annoying is that the output PDF has the wrong hierarchy in bookmarks since References and Index appear as belonging to the Appendix:

[image]

If I use `\part{References}` then I get a whole page saying "References" with huge letters and I really don't want that. I would like the References and the Index to look in the Table of Contents just as "Apéndices" looks like but being independent sections in bookmarks.

**EDIT**: This is the essential part of what precedes the last part of my code in case it helps.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
% ----------     BibLaTex     ------------ %
\usepackage[style=american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, citestyle=numeric,bibstyle=authoryear,url=true,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  bibliography = {Referencias},
}
% ----------      Hyperref    ------------ %
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=true, 
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black} 
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
% ---------    Cuerpo del documento  -------------- %
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\part{Medida y Categoría}
\appendix
```

Comment: By the way, you _do_ know that nobody will ever care what the pdf-bookmark-hierarchy of the appendix of your Thesis looks like, don't you? ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) to your preamble repertoir (after loading [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)) and issue `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` immediately after `\backmatter`.

According to the [`bookmark` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/bookmark.pdf) (section **1.2.5 Level options**, p 5):

> The order of the bookmark entries are defined by the appearance order of `\bookmark` commands. The tree structure is constructed by the property `level` of the bookmark nodes. The values of `level` are integers. If the level of a bookmark entry has a higher value than the previous node, then the entry becomes a child of the previous node. The absolute value of the difference does not matter.
>
> Package `bookmark` remembers the level of the previous bookmark entry in a global property ‘current level’.
>
> The behaviour of the level system can be configured by following options:
>
> **`level`**: Sets the level, see the description above. If option level is given without
>   value, then the default behaviour is restored, that the ‘current level’ is
>   used as level value. Since version 2010/10/19 v1.16 package `bookmark` also
>   supports names `part`, `section` and other, if the macros `\toclevel@part`,
>   `\toclevel@section` are defined (done by package [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), see option `bookmarkdepth`).
>
> **`rellevel`**: Sets the level relative to the previous level. A positive value means that the bookmark entry become a child of the previous one.
>
> **`keeplevel`**: Use the level, set by `level` or `rellevel`, but do not change the global property ‘current level’. The option can be disabled by setting to false.
>
> **`startatroot`**: At this time the bookmark tree starts at the top level again. The
>   next bookmark entry is not sorted as child to a previous entry. Example
>   scenario: A document uses part. However there are last chapters that should
>   not be put below the last part:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{book}
> [...]
> \begin{document}
>   \part{First part}
>     \chapter{First chapter in first part}
>     [...]
>   \part{Second part}
>     \chapter{First chapter in second part}
>     [...]
>   \bookmarksetup{startatroot}
>   \chapter{Index}% does not belong to second part
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: When I click on for instance an appendix content which is in an appendices environment, It goes to cover page instead. Is there any further option needed here? I use \bookmarksetup{startaroot} before \begin{appendices} but nothing happens.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: That typically means that you're resetting counters which creates duplicate PDF destinations references. There must be some reference to that in your `.log`. It would require more for me to gauge on how to fix that...

Comment: I solved my problem by adding `\appendix` after `\begin{appendices}` with aid of `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}`

Answer (score 2):

One quick way to fix this might be telling *hyperref* to insert an additional bookmark:

```
% ------     Referencias  ---------- %
\pdfbookmark[-1]{Referencias y Indices}{BM-Referencias}  
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

I had some difficulties with your MWE, so you might need to adjust some of the parameters to get it working:

- `[-1]`: indicate what level (relative to the current) to put the bookmark.
- `{Referencias y Indices}`: text to print into the hierarchy
- `{BM-Referencias}`: something like a label, needs to be unique.

Comment: +1 Just being nitpicking, "Referencias e Índices" (the capital I with an accent) would be the correct spelling in Spanish :-)

Comment: :-D I did not know that, @Gonzalo. But as long as the encoding is set correct, accents in the bookmark should be fine.